# PHP Encode column _id without double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding

Encoding database data into JSON using following script:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["detail"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $item = array();
            $item["_id"] = $row["_id"];

            array_push($response["detail"], $item);
           }
      // success
     $response["success"] = 1;
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

And getting response like this:

```
{"detail":[{"_id":"3"}],"success":1}
```

Whereas I was expecting this one:

```
{"detail":[{"_id":3}],"success":1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag introduced in `5.3.0`.

```
echo json_encode( $response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```

Please read this for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Or

you may type cast the `int` id

```
 $item["_id"] = (int) $row["_id"];
```

Comment: thank you :) ticked as useful and will accept in five minutes